# Циклы C++ , while

Tags: c++, while

Можно получить предположим input 15 output будет 10 11 12 13.. а не 15 14 ..?

```
int main() {
    unsigned i; 
    std::cin >> i; 
    while (i >= 10) { 
        std::cout << i << " "; 
        --i; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Да, можно. Для этого нужно просто немного подумать

Answer (score 3):

С минимальными изменениями:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned i,j;
    std::cin>> i; j=i;
    while (i>=10) {
        std::cout<< 10 + (j - i) <<" "; --i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой-то очень хитрый вариант.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я так понял, что надо без изменения условия `while` сделать

Comment: Хм, если так, тогда да.